# Socket.io "Session ID unknown" error on Heroku

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io

I have a Node JS app using Socket.io deployed to heroku. I have followed the steps provided at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets to setup the code properly but somehow it seems like I am unable to use Web sockets properly.

All my socket polling requests are failing with the following error.

> {"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}

The same code seems to be working fine when I run it locally.

**Client**

```
function createSocket() {
        socket = io();

        socket.on('connect', function () {
            socket.emit('registerUser', { userEmail: $scope.userInfo.userEmail });
        });

 socket.on('list_of_files', function (data) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.fileList = data;
            });

        });
    }
```

**Server**

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('registerUser', function (data) {
            socketClients[data.userEmail] = socket;
        });
    });
```

I have also enabled heroku's session affinity but still no luck

Comment: Which version were you using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i know its too late but for those who still looking for the answer try adding this option on the client socket.

```
{
path: '/socket.io',
transports: ['websocket'],
secure: true,
}
```

also just for your information i'm having this problem after deploying to staging server with nginx and proxy

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Dude NO. The problem is that sticky sessions do not work. If you use websocket then you dont solve the problem, you just deactivated long polling which is an important feature of socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

Same question on iOS platform, "session id unknown ..."

before

```
[[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:url config:@{@"log": @NO, @"forcePolling":@YES, @"reconnectWait":@1}];
```

after

```
[[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:url config:@{@"log": @NO, @"forcePolling":@YES, @"forceWebsockets":@YES}];
```

Answer (score 0):

When running on heroku and you have multiple dynos, you need to make sure that HTTP requests are associated with the same dyno for socket.io to work. This is also known as sticky sessions. You can enable sticky sessions like this:

`heroku features:disable http-session-affinity -a <app name>`

Read more about it [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity).